# If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, does $\mathbb{E}[{X+Y|X}] = X + \mathbb{E}[Y]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, does $\mathbb{E}[{X+Y|X}] = X + \mathbb{E}[Y]$? Note: The answer is still a random variable.$\\$ I should add that I derived this law from the following statements: $$\mathbb{E}[{X+Y|X}] = \mathbb{E}[{X|X}] + \mathbb{E}[{Y|X}] \\ =X + \mathbb{E}[{Y|X}] \\ = X + \mathbb{E}[Y]$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider, for instance, if $X$ is any random variable and $Y=X$.

Comment: What if they are independent?

Comment: Then it should hold, yes.